# How can I debug a NullPointerException where the stacktrace doesn't reference my classes?

Tags: java, debugging, javafx, stack-trace

I have a table whose rows are filtered based on a text input.

I recently put the predicate in a delayed system (full code below) to avoid freezing the UI while the large dataset is filtered.

I can generate the following exception by spamming the filter input text box right as the program launches. As you will see, the entire exception takes place within Oracle's code base. I don't see any of my project's classes on the stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList$Element.access$200(SortedList.java:272)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.get(SortedList.java:170)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:562)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.requestCellUpdate(TableRowSkinBase.java:659)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.lambda$init$0(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.Cell.setItem(Cell.java:403)
    at javafx.scene.control.Cell.updateItem(Cell.java:670)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.updateItem(TableRow.java:259)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.indexChanged(TableRow.java:225)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1957)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.addTrailingCells(VirtualFlow.java:1344)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellCount(VirtualFlow.java:231)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkinBase.updateRowCount(TableViewSkinBase.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualContainerBase.checkState(VirtualContainerBase.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualContainerBase.layoutChildren(VirtualContainerBase.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkinBase.layoutChildren(TableViewSkinBase.java:696)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$3(Toolkit.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code I recently added is this, replacing the normal way of doing filtering of a table. The basic idea is to avoid applying predicates that aren't necessary.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import net.joshuad.hypnos.Album;

public class ThrottledAlbumFilter {
    private String requestedFilter = "";
    private long timeRequestMadeMS = 0;

    private Thread filterThread;
    private boolean interruptFiltering = false;

    private String currentAppliedFilter = "";

    private FilteredList <Album> filteredList;

    public ThrottledAlbumFilter ( FilteredList <Album> filteredList ) {
        this.filteredList = filteredList;

        filterThread = new Thread ( () -> {
            while ( true ) {
                String filter = requestedFilter;

                if ( !filter.equals( currentAppliedFilter ) ) {
                    if ( System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeRequestMadeMS + 100 ) {
                        interruptFiltering = false;
                        setPredicate( filter );
                        currentAppliedFilter = filter;
                    }
                }

                try { Thread.sleep( 25 ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {} 
            }
        });

        filterThread.setDaemon( true );
        filterThread.start();
    }

    public void setFilter ( String filter ) {
        if ( filter == null ) filter = "";
        timeRequestMadeMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.requestedFilter = filter;
        interruptFiltering = true;
    }

    private void setPredicate ( String filterText ) {
        filteredList.setPredicate( album -> {
            if ( interruptFiltering ) return true;
            if ( filterText.isEmpty() ) return true;

            ArrayList <String> matchableText = new ArrayList <String>();

            matchableText.add( album.getAlbumArtist().toLowerCase() );
            matchableText.add( album.getYear().toLowerCase() );
            matchableText.add( album.getFullAlbumTitle().toLowerCase() );

            matchableText.add( Normalizer.normalize( album.getFullAlbumTitle(), Normalizer.Form.NFD )
                .replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" ).toLowerCase() 
            );

            matchableText.add( Normalizer.normalize( album.getYear(), Normalizer.Form.NFD )
                .replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" ).toLowerCase()
            );

            matchableText.add( Normalizer.normalize( album.getAlbumArtist(), Normalizer.Form.NFD )
                .replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" ).toLowerCase() 
            );

            String[] lowerCaseFilterTokens = filterText.toLowerCase().split( "\\s+" );
            for ( String token : lowerCaseFilterTokens ) {
                boolean tokenMatches = false;
                for ( String test : matchableText ) {
                    if ( test.contains( token ) ) {
                        tokenMatches = true;
                    }
                }

                if ( !tokenMatches ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

The previous version was heavily tested and had no problems. Now, I can generate it pretty dependably by quickly changing the filter text a lot right as the program is starting. I have to assume the crash is arising as a result of this changed code, but since my stack trace doesn't reference my codebase at all, I'm not really sure where to start.

edit: Interestingly, changing that sleep to 50ms from 25ms seems to squash the bug on my computer. That makes me very nervous, because I have to imagine the "right" value is different for different speed systems.

Comment: Try wrapping your Runnable body in a try/catch.

Comment: I'd be careful to ensure that any change which might effect the UI is done from within the UI main thread

Comment: i think the new thread object creation can be put inside try catch so that precisely catch the exception line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely concurrency issue.

The `TableView` is trying to render during a render pulse, and the backing list is changing when this is happening. `NullPointerException` is being thrown because the `Element` object holding the actual element has "mysteriously" disappeared.

Relying on sleep time is a very bad idea - I'm sure you have realized that as well. There are two main methods to solve this:

#### Modifying UI on the UI thread (i.e. JavaFX Application thread)

You can do the same, except that you would wrap the `filteredList.setPredicate()` call in `Platform.runLater()`.

In other words, it should look like this:

```
final Predicate<Album> predicate = album -> {
    // Whatever you have
};

Platform.runLater(() -> filteredList.setPredicate(predicate));
```

Doing this will off-load the generation of `Predicate` in the background thread, while the actual updating is done on the UI thread. I would say that this will cause a good chunk of processing to be shifted back to UI thread as well, but it is probably unavoidable.

However, you can still skip some predicate changes, because of the codes you have written in the `Runnable` object in the thread. I assume this fulfills your requirement of "avoiding applying predicates that aren't necessary."

#### Use TimeLine

JavaFX has this very handy class called `TimeLine` that works like a timer, and it runs on the UI thread.

Instead of using another thread, create a single `TimeLine` object in your class.

```
private String filter;

private final Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100),
                 ae -> setPredicate()
    ));

public void setFilter ( String filter ) {
    if ( filter == null ) filter = "";
    if ( !this.filter.equals( filter ) ) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.timeline.playFromStart();
    }
}

private void setPredicate() {
    final String filterText = this.filter;

    // The rest remains pretty much the same.
}
```

Using this approach causes all codes to run on UI thread, so you will not have those weird exceptions.

Another good thing is, you will not have to manage the thread. Although you have set the thread to daemon, the thread will still run the `Runnable` every 25ms until your program totally terminates.

Lastly, this provides a uniform delay that starts from the last change in the filter string. This will provide a slightly better user experience.